# How to replace US phone number format onkeypress and limit the length?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to limit the length of numbers when key is pressed:

```
 var regx = /^[0-9]+$/;    
$("#login_email_or_mob").keyup(function(){

var mob_or_email = $("#login_email_or_mob").val();  

    if(regx.test(mob_or_email)) {

            if(mob_or_email.length==11){
            this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3');
            }
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: You said onkeypress but your code is keyup? Also note that the keyboard events only fire on keyboard changes. If I paste in "abc12345" it will allow it since the keyboard events do not fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're matching the first ten characters and replacing them only. The other characters remain intact. To change this behaviour, select them as well with `.*`:

```
if(regx.test(this.value)) {
    if(this.value.length==11){
      this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4}).*/,'$1-$2-$3'));
    }
}
```